# On Click of previous button in the screen flow, using custom Lightning Web Components can Persist Data in the local browser storage

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, screen-flow

We have a requirement with screenflow, I would to know whether it is possible or not?

- We have screen flow in the salesforce with 5 screens(A,B,C,D,E).
- In the 5 screens we have used the LWC component in the 2
  screens(C,E).
- And when we are clicking on continue button we are saving those lwc
  data to database.

Let's say now user is on the screen C and he filled 3 fields on the LWC component on the screen "C", now he wants to go previous screen that is "B" and update few details and with onclick on continue on the "B" screen he came back to Screen "C".

1. Now Whatever entered in those 3 fields(LWC) previously in the screen "C" data should exist or persists ?
2. Can we do this without using api call to apex ? with any browser
   local storage cache?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - browsers offer several options,

you can use [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [indexDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API)

If you only need to store a few field values, i would suggest using localstorage.